# Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

pls help to to fix these errors

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...
6 actionable tasks: 6 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[img here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNVQ7.png)

Comment: Please launch your Emulator from Android studio manually and then run your project

Comment: @Ouneeb Ur Rehman how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Greetings Friend,

A picture is worth a thousand words.
Close all projects so you will have box like in the image above.

Once there, launch the device like this:

[image]

Comment: not working i have tried this what you have told